# Cannot connect Eclipse to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I see this error message when I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL from Eclipse.

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication
>   failed for user "postgres"    at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:415)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:188)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:143)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:38)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
>     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:412)    at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)    at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.createConnection(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:87)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
>     at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Comment: The error kind of explains the problem. `password authentication failed for user "postgres" `. Presumably you used the wrong password for the user `postgres`.

Answer (score 1):

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"` tells you the error, that your password failed to authenticate for the `postgres` user.

Fix the password using `psql` and `\password` and verify your `pg_hba.conf` using the [pg_hba.conf documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

(Edited to take @CraigRinger's comments on the allowed authentication methods of PgJDBC into account)

Comment: `peer` isn't likely to work since Eclipse will be using PgJDBC which only supports TCP/IP, not unix sockets. Almost nothing runs an identd, so ident won't tend to work either. Really, it's a matter of getting the password right.